# PrimeFaces chips does not add items

Tags: jsf, primefaces

After deploy this code i go to browser and put some data in input field and press enter. It should add text to chips but it doesn't i don't have idea why plaease help.

xhtml code

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
        <h:head>
            <title>Chips</title>  
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            Chips
            <br/>
            <h:form>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <p:outputLabel value="Add Color"/>
                    <p:chips />
                    <p:outputLabel for="display" value="Avaiable Colors"/>
                    <p:chips id="display" value="#{colors.colors}"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </html>
```

I use this java class for xhtml with use JSF and PrimeFaces.

```java
@ViewScoped
@Data
@Named
public class Colors implements Serializable{
    private List<String> colors;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        colors = new ArrayList<>();
        colors.add("Red");
        colors.add("Blue");
        colors.add("Green");
        colors.add("Yellow");
        colors.add("Orange");
        colors.add("Purple");
    }
}
```

This is my pom.xml file maybe here something is missing. Please help it's look everything fine.

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pl.mz</groupId>
    <artifactId>Primefaces-YtTutorial</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <jakarta.jakartaee-api.version>8.0.0</jakarta.jakartaee-api.version>
        <microprofile.version>3.0</microprofile.version>
        <mockito-core.version>3.1.0</mockito-core.version>
        <junit-jupiter.version>5.5.0</junit-jupiter.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakarta.jakartaee-api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile</groupId>
            <artifactId>microprofile</artifactId>
            <version>${microprofile.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.20</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.0</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito-core.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                    <version>3.12.0</version>
                </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>Primefaces-YtTutorial</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Your `<p:chips />` is not bound to anything so there is nothing for it to submit?

Comment: It's should look like here https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/chips.xhtml?jfwid=4111f  you put some text after press enter it change pls checkout this. But in my case after enter nothing happend :(. Even if i copy code from link it's not work for me like there.

Answer (score 0):

I add not visible commandButton and this start work corectly. But i hope someone will show me beter why to solve this issue or will point some bug in my code. I leave my solution here.

```
        <h:form>         
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <p:outputLabel value="Add Color"/>
            <p:chips/>
            <p:outputLabel for="display" value="Avaiable Colors"/>
            <p:chips id="display" value="#{colors.colors}"/>          
        </h:panelGrid>
        <p:commandButton rendered="false"/>
    </h:form>
```